# getting access to the path denied while saving a zip file using DotNetZip library

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am trying to create a zip file and save it using DotNetZip library.

But for some reason i get a "Access to the path is denied" error when i try to save it. Code4 is below

```
Dim zipFile As New ZipFile()
zipFile.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression
zipFile.AddFile(filePath)
Dim tempFilePath As String = "abc.zip"
zipFile.TempFileFolder = "D:\Company Data\Operations\media\test_folder_cover_scan\"
zipFile.Save(tempFilePath) <== error line
```

I have given all possible access to the folder. I am using .net 3.5. This whole code works in a web service

Please advise

Comment: What access have you give and to which user/groups?

Comment: i have given full access  to aspnet process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslashes in your `TempFileFolder` are not escaped which might cause a problem.  Try using a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(VS.71).aspx) instead.

```
zipFile.TempFileFolder = @"D:\Company Data\Operations\media\test_folder_cover_scan\"
```

Also, the `tempFilePath` in your example doesn't include a full path, could it be that it is trying to save the ZIP into a different folder from the one you are expecting (and have assigned permissions to)?

Have you assigned permissions to *both* the temporary file folder AND the real destination folder?

Comment: thanks as you pointed out the zip file was saving in some other folder.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have access to where you are trying to save it to.  Try opening the command prompt and typing

```
takeown /f D:\Company Data\Operations\media\test_folder_cover_scan
```

That should give you ownership to the folder you are trying to save the file to.