# DotNetZip library "Access to the path denied"

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, dotnetzip

I am trying to create a zip file and save it using DotNetZip library in ASP.NET application.
But for some reason i get a

> Access to the path is denied

error when i try to save it.

I changed the `TempFileFolder` to another folder and have given permissions to it. Still no luck.

```
Dim zipFile As New ZipFile()
zipFile.AddFile(filePath)
Dim tempFilePath As String = "Report.zip"
zipFile.TempFileFolder = "D:\Temp\"
zipFile.Save(tempFilePath);
```

I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619241/getting-access-to-the-path-denied-while-saving-a-zip-file-using-dotnetzip-librar/3619301#3619301) but the answer did not help me.

From the above question, one answer mentioned:

> Also, the tempFilePath in your example doesn't include a full path, could it be that it is trying to save the ZIP into a different folder from the one you are expecting (and have assigned permissions to)?

How to figure out to which folder it is trying to save even though I mentioned `TempFileFolder` as `D:\temp\`?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Since you said you 'gave permissions' I'm assuming that you provided the account(s) which run the ASP.NET and IIS processes file Read/Write permissions to the folder where you're trying to save this file.

The 'Temp File Folder' is just what its name describes: a temporary file folder. It's a holding place in case the library needs to do some file I/O. it's not a base file.

Modify the code to provide a fully qualified path name to save the file to:

```
Dim zipFile As New ZipFile()
zipFile.AddFile(filePath)
Dim tempFilePath As String = "D:\Temp\Report.zip"
zipFile.TempFileFolder = "D:\Temp\"
zipFile.Save(tempFilePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file is not Read Only